# How can I set page properties using Power Automate with HTTP Request JSON?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, flow, power-automate

I'd create a flow in the Power Automate where a new page will be created by an HTTP Request with JSON.

I can replace and set text into the new page via the JSON, but I don't know how I can set the page properties.

Comment: You want to set the page properties or SharePoint site properties?

Comment: The page proberties

Comment: which page properties you are trying to update?

Comment: In the page library I created own column as properties and assinged them as page properties to display them on my pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the page properties using **Send an HTTP request to SharePoint** action like:

[image]

**Method**: `POST`

**Uri**:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items(1)
```

**Headers**:

```
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
If-Match: *
X-HTTP-Method: MERGE
```

**Body**:

```
{
    "__metadata": {"type":"SP.Data.SitePagesItem"},
    "Title": "Custom title set by flow"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: You mean I should update my new created page in a next step and adding then the properties?

Comment: Yes, you can add one more action & perform update operation as given in my answer. Pass the item ID (in Uri) from dynamic data of previous action used to create a page.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I tried with your example. But it isn't working. I can set the title but no more other properties. Do you know why?

Comment: Which properties are you trying to set? Are you getting any error (if yes, please post the error message)? Did you create custom columns? If Yes, did you add them to the all content types in "Site Pages" library?

Comment: Also, make sure you are using correct internal name of your columns in request body.